# Bypass JWT with GraphQL and jwt-express

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, graphql

For my backend, I use Node.js, Express, and GraphQL. I've implemented authentication with jwt which will protect my routes if there's no user logged in. The problem is that I want some routes not protected, i.e. you shouldn't have to be logged in to see `/home`.

Since I'm using Express to this project I also have jwt-express and they provide something like this: `.unless({path: ['/token']})`.Now, this would work if I had a REST-API, but since I have GraphQL and GraphQL only have one path this won't work.

I only have this in my `index.js` file:

```
app.use(jwt({secret: constants.JWT_SECRET}))

app.use(
 graphqlEndpoint,
 bodyParser.json(),
 graphqlExpress(async req => {
   let user = null
   if (req.user) {
     user = await knex(‘users’).where(‘id’, req.user.id).first()
     console.log(user)
   }
   return {
     schema,
     context: {user}
   }
 })
)
```

But I have to make sure that it lets me in regardless, without or with a token.

So I simply wonder if anyone has some tips on how to accomplish this since I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: Can you please share with me your approach I'm stuck onto this for the last one week. if I add login(one graphqlExpress but graphql endpoints same ) before middleware I can't access the other entities(other graphqlExpress but endpoints graphql same).If I add within the same graphqlExpress function the error is no token found as here I've added the middleware. .I google but no close solution. And thankfully I found your post. Please, help me out I'm stuck :(

Comment: @Tested Ditto. Any solution on this or sources? Would love some direction on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `app.use(jwt({secret: constants.JWT_SECRET}))`, it will read JWT in every request. There are 2 options:

- You apply middleware in the specific routes that you want
  authenticated.
- You should add login route before the use of jwt.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I have to do a whole lot of googling now hehe

Answer (score 0):

You can specify express-jwt to let unregistered users through:

```
app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'hello world !',
  credentialsRequired: false
}));
```

Source: express-jwt's README.md
https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt